# Javascript move image across page on click and reset image to original location after some time

Tags: javascript

I'm kicking myself over this, but I cannot figure out a way to 1) have an image move across the screen on click (clicking the image itself), and 2) have the image reset to the original location after 10 or so seconds with no clicks using Javascript, as I am relatively new to using JS over pure CSS animation. Are there any solutions (preferably without using jQuery)?

I will eventually be replacing this image with an APNG file that will need to begin playing on click and end upon reset, so any suggestions on how to incorporate this would be helpful!`

JavaScript Animation

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     //<!--
        var imgObj = null;
        var animate ;

        function init(){
           imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
           imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
           imgObj.style.top = '400px'; 
        }

        function moveTop(){
           imgObj.style.top = parseInt(imgObj.style.top) - 10 + 'px';
           animate = setTimeout(moveTop,20); 
        }

        //function stop(){
           //clearTimeout(animate);
           //imgObj.style.top = '0px'; 
        //}

        window.onload =init;
     //-->
  </script>
```

```
     <input type="image" id="myImage" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn-origin-etr.akc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/13001000/Beagle-On-White-01-400x267.jpg" onclick="moveTop();"  />
     <!--<input type="image" src="/images/html.gif" onclick="stop();"  />-->
```

`

Comment: What have you tried so far? As this question stands, there's too many moving parts (pun intended) to write a concise answer. Read some tutorials about `animate`, event delegation (`$("element").on("click", function(){ ... });`), etc. When you've tried something, post a specific question with errors and you're more likely to get a response.

Comment: Also, look at CSS transitions/animations. I think you could possible run an animation on the `:active` selector.

Comment: Unfortunately with :active, the animation only runs when the mouse is pushed down. It would be so much easier if this wasn't the case! I have code above that allows me to click the image and have it move, but now I would love to be able to reset it after some time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT] forgot to add the wait, see the comment in the code

If your code does the initial animation to the top, I would suggest this simple change.

It also accounts for overshooting the target.

### For this to work you need to:

- Copy both functions below into your code
- Pass the desired target value in the **onclick** function

  ```
  function moveTop(var target){
     imgObj.style.top = parseInt(imgObj.style.top) - 10 + 'px';
     if(parseInt(imgObj.style.top) < target)
     {
         imgObj.style.top = target + 'px';
     }

     if(parseInt(imgObj.style.top) - 10 > target)
     {
         animate = setTimeout(function() {moveTop(target);},20);
     }
     else
     {
         //add the wait here, currently 5 seconds
         animate = setTimeout(function() {moveBack(400);},5000);
     }
  }

  function moveBack(var target){
     imgObj.style.top = parseInt(imgObj.style.top) + 10 + 'px';
     if(parseInt(imgObj.style.top) > target)
     {
         imgObj.style.top = target + 'px';
     }

     if(parseInt(imgObj.style.top) + 10 < target)
     {
         animate = setTimeout(function() {moveBack(400);},20);
     }
  }
  ```

Comment: @Karasel I've made a few changes and am checking it over now

Comment: @Karasel I believe that should work well now. With a 5 second wait to start moving the element back to the position 400px